# Android 'Fullscreen' menu design?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, user-experience

Sorry about the less than helpful title,

I'm currently looking to design a menu such as the one in the image below, it is not a list view which i would at first assume, as it is simply 5 static buttons in a menu,

anyway, to my question, Is this menu (which is highly reminiscent of ICS Holo) built into the ICS Library along the same lines as the ActionBar or ActionBarCompat

Sorry if i'm being so vague, i rarely have UI/design questions, so not sure where to start!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK9oN.png

Comment: Its not displayed using the menu button, sorry the image is less than helpful at getting that across, its just a default navigation page.

Comment: context menu is opened on long press event